# local variable and global variable

Tags: c, function

When I run my program it gives the error:

```
Segmentation fault
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
add (int sum)
{
  int count = 1;

  sum = sum + count;
  count++;
  if (count <= 4)
    {
      add (sum);
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("sum=%d\n", sum);
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  int sum = 0;
  add (sum);

  return 0;
}
```

When I change `count` from a local variable to a global variable, the program works. Why doesn't the program work when the variable `count` is initialized in function `add` as a local variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `count` is a global variable, it will be initialized to 1 only when the program is run.

If `count` is a local variable, but not a `static`, it will be initialised to 1 every time `add()` is entered. To prevent this, declare it as

```
static int count = 1;
```

What the other answers are not telling you is why you are getting a `segmentation fault`. The reason for this is that if you always initialise `count` to 1, it will always call `add()` from within `add()`. Each time you do this you use up stack space, until the stack is exhausted and attempts to overwrite whatever is beyond the stack. *That's* what is giving you the segmentation fault. Technically, this is called a **Stack Overflow**, hence the name of this site.

Comment: There should be a bingo every time a question on stack overflow is caused by a stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you have a local variable `count`, anytime you enter the function `add()` it will set `count` to 1. Your code is incrementing `count` then checking to see if it's greater less than or equal to 4, and if not it's calling `add()` again. This will loop forever because 2 will always be less than 4.

You need the variable to be a local `static int` or global variable. In both cases you'll initialize it to 1 and it will retain the last value set. I would use a `static int` here instead of a global... in general globals are considered bad practice without a good reason for using them.

Answer (score 1):

When your method **add(int sum)**  has been executed the count will always get the value 1 again.

So this will cause an endless recursion and eventually segfault.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize `count` as local variable in your method, it creates a recursion that never ends. Each time it enters the function `count` 'resets' to 1. It will never reach the value that is needed to leave the function.

When you create `count` as global variable it only gets assigned 1 once, and every time the function is executed it adds 1 so after 4 times it can safely exit.